# How to pass application name for New Relic Insights in Spring boot micrometer

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, newrelic, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I successfully configured New Relic with micrometer, but I've observed that there is no application name sent along.

I would like to include it in order to be able filter on different environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to retrieve `app_name` from New Relic using `newrelic-api`:

```
NewRelic.getAgent().config.getValue("app_name")
```

Having this value I've just passed it to `commonTags` inside `MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry>`